# Check if Capybara::Node::Element has been removed by jQuery.remove()

Tags: jquery, tdd, capybara, ruby-on-rails-5

I'm trying to make the following test:

```
it 'remove item from cart' do
  visit cart_path
  button = page.find("a[href='/carts/#{item.id}/remove']")
  card = find_ancestor_with_class(button, '.card')
  button.click
  # check if card has been removed from page
end
```

This test is suppossed to work because the following JS removes the card from page:

```
$.ajax({
  url: link,
  method: "GET",
  success: function() {
    $('#alert-modal').modal('show');
    $(button).closest(".card").remove();
  }
});
```

How I verify if the `.card` html has been removed from page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To check if something isn't visible on the page you would do

```
expect(page).to have_no_css(".card")
```

or

```
expect(page).not_to have_css(".card")
```

So overall it becomes

```
visit cart_path
click_link(href: "/cars/#{item.id}/remove")    
expect(page).not_to have_css(".card")
```

That will only work if all the `.card` elements are removed. If there would still be other `.card` elements on the page then base the check on text that you expect to be in the card or other attribute/property on the card element (id, etc), like the items description or whatever would be shown like

```
expect(page).not_to have_css(".card", text: item.description)
```

If you deal with the `.card` elements a lot you could also write a custom Capybara selector to make things easier to read, localize the CSS definition of a "card" etc like

```
Capybara.add_selector :card do
  xpath do |content| 
    xp = XPath.css('.card')
    xp = xp[XPath.string.n.is(content)] unless content.nil?
    xp
  end
end
```

which should then allow

```
expect(page).to have_no_selector(:card)
expect(page).to have_no_selector(:card, item.description)
```

etc.

Comment: But there isn't a way to check using `card`?

Comment: @RodrigoChaves Not really, depending on exactly how `card` is located, when the element is removed `card` may actually point to a new element,  as can be seen in the demo - https://gist.github.com/twalpole/ac5c893a6f1f27ba3005908421d3e45d - in which `card` ends up pointing to all three `.card` elements on the page as elements are removed.  This is because of Capybaras automatic reloading which deals with dynamic page refreshes/reloads.  Tests should really focus on what the user sees on the page rather than worrying about specific elements.